# ¿Por qué no me funciona el método mysqli_affected_rows?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy aprendiendo bases de datos y tras hacer una función que borra filas correctamente, añado mysqli_affected_rows para ver las filas afectadas y sale siempre un error o, si no, "0" (cuando se ha eliminado una fila). He probado de todas las maneras y no lo logro y no me parece que deba de ser muy complicado. A ver si alguien me ilumina. Os pongo la función:

```
   function borrarLibro($libro) {

  $this->libro = $libro;

  $query = "DELETE FROM libro WHERE id = '$libro'";

  $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion(), $query);

  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {

     for ($i = 0; $i < count($fila); $i++) {
        echo $fila [$i] . " ";
     }
     
           
  }
  echo "Se han borrado " . mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexion($query)) .  " fila(s)";
  $resultado = mysqli_close($this->conexion());
```

}

y el error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_row(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionLibros.php:134 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocsgestionLibros.php(134): mysqli_fetch_row(true) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\index_tarea_6.php(45): gestionLibros->borrarLibro(3) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestionLibros.php on line 134
```

He hecho unos cambios y sigue sin funcionar:

```
   function borrarLibro($libro) {

  $this->libro = $libro;
  
  if(!$this->conexion()->query("DELETE FROM libro WHERE id = '$libro'")){
     
  }
  echo "Se han borrado " . mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexion()) .  " fila(s)";
  $resultado = mysqli_close($this->conexion());
```

}

Comment: Si haces un `var_dump` de `$resultado` ¿Qué obtienes?

Comment: Da exactamente el mismo error, acabo de percatarme de que el error en sí que muestra la pantalla viene de la variable $resultado y no de affected_rows :S pero eliminar, elimina la fila.

Comment: Creo que el problema es el bucle for, como solo puede hacer una fila con ese id, sobra. Voy a probar a quitarlo.

Comment: Saludos. Lee la documentación de dicha función (https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) la sentencia `DELETE` no devuelve un resultado de filas afectadas); puede te equivocaste y lo que quieres es saber el total de filas afectadas (no cuales; https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Comment: @Roberto creo que el enlace que buscas es este https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: He cambiado alguna cosa y lo he añadido debajo de la pregunta original. Efectivamente, yo solo quiero ver el número de filas afectadas (entiendo que si se borra una fila, tiene que poner que una fila ha sido afectada).